# How do you suppress warnings coming from Prometheus library?

Tags: elixir

We use an external library [`Prometeus`](https://hexdocs.pm/prometheus_ex/Prometheus.html) in our code base that generates warnings in Elixir 1.11. Usually, this wouldn't be a problem, but we treat warnings as errors when compiling our code base to ensure code quality. Is there a way we can suppress the warnings from this one macro?

Example using `{:prometheus_plugs, "1.1.5"}` and Elixir 1.11.2:

```
defmodule Company.Api.PrometheusExporter do
  use Prometheus.PlugPipelineInstrumenter
end
```

Gives this output:

```
==> api
Compiling 99 files (.ex)
warning: System.stacktrace/0 is deprecated, use __STACKTRACE__ instead
  lib/api/pipeline_instrumenter.ex:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the lastest version of prometheus_ex: https://github.com/deadtrickster/prometheus.ex/commit/dea38d0b2c8edc2c8c97979f42f06d48135a12b6.

I would upgrade the dependency to the latest commit for the time being in your
`mix.exs` file:

Change

```
  {:prometheus_ex, "~> 3.0.6"}
```

to

```
  # We need to use the master branch of prometheus_ex because it contains a fix for a warning
  # that is not released yet. The commit containing the fix is
  # https://github.com/deadtrickster/prometheus.ex/commit/dea38d0b2c8edc2c8c97979f42f06d48135a12b6.
  # We should change this to `{:prometheus_ex, "~> 3.0.6"},` when the fix is released
  # (changing the version to the correct one). The latest broken version is 3.0.5
  {:prometheus_ex, git: "https://github.com/deadtrickster/prometheus.ex", override: true},
```

Comment: This does not answer the question stated by any means, though. I will change the title of the question to fit this answer.

Comment: Yea, I did have a generic warning suppressor answer, but it unfortunately it did not work as perfectly as I had expected and had to remove that part of the answer :(